# Twig - How to call a object method using variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to fill a grid, but I don't know how call a object method using a variable. Variable "menus" is my entities, and "itens" is an array with what I wanna show in this grid.

```
    $itens = array(
            array('name' => 'id', 'label' => 'Id'),
            array('name' => 'parent', 'label' => 'Pai'),
            array('name' => 'name', 'label' => 'Nome'),
            array('name' => 'route', 'label' => 'Rota'),
            array('name' => 'position', 'label' => 'Posição'),
    );
```

Here's my code:

```
{% for menu in menus %}
    <tr>
        {% for item in itens %}
            <td>{{ attribute(menu, item['name']) }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried too with menu.item['name'], but without success... Any idea?

Comment: can you post the results of `{{ dump(item) }}` inside your for loop? Just need to see the structure

Comment: array(2) { ["name"]=> string(2) "id" ["label"]=> string(2) "Id" } 
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(6) "parent" ["label"]=> string(3) "Pai" } 
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "name" ["label"]=> string(4) "Nome" } 
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "route" ["label"]=> string(4) "Rota" } 
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "position" ["label"]=> string(9) "Posição" }

Comment: Ricardo, não é só isso... estou tentando acessar um atributo de um objeto que está dentro de uma variavel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it!!! I did this:

```
    {% for menu in menus %}
        <tr>
            {% for item in itens %}
                {% set method %}{{ item['name'] }}{% endset %}
               <td>{{ attribute(menu, method) }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```